# Does WhatsApp work without a SIM card?

Tags: iphone, sim, whatsapp.app

In my Moto G5, I can still use WhatsApp after removing the SIM card, after I successfully validated my phone number.

Would this method work in an iPhone?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, a Sim Card is not required to use Whatsapp. Whatsapp doesn't use your network provider to function as text messages do. Text messages require a Sim Card to recieve the message to your phone number.

> A SIM, or Subscriber Identity Module, card is a computer chip inside a cell phone which identifies your device to your service provider. SIM cards can contain up to 128 KB of memory to store things like contacts, phone numbers, text messages, data usage and billing information.

([Source](https://www.techwalla.com/articles/does-a-sim-card-store-text-messages))

Whereas, Whatsapp doesn't use your phone number to receive messages. It uses your phone number to make an account to which messages can be sent and received.

If you are setting up an account with the phone with no Sim, make sure you have your Sim in to receive the verification code.

> You can now use WhatsApp on devices without a SIM card. All you need is a SIM card and a phone number that is not registered on WhatApp to install the app. Once your WhatsApp account is activated, you can continue using it on other devices without the SIM card.

([Source](https://www.techworm.net/2015/08/how-to-install-and-use-whatsapp-without-a-sim-card.html/amp))

Answer (score 1):

Yes, if you are looking for a similar approach where you have the SIM card plugged in just for the activation part.

No, if you are looking for activating two instances of same WhatsApp account, using the same SIM card number on two different phones simultaneously.

Comment: Thanks for your answer @Nimesh Neema. I validated WhatsApp in my Moto G5 when I bought it months ago. My SIM card is now in a Nokia 130 classic with no Internet access, just for calls and SMS. According to your answer, this setup will work when moving to an IPhone, right?

Comment: @biotech Please mention is the SIM card in question is the same? i.e., the same SIM is currently being used in Nokia 130 Classic that you used to validate WhatsApp in Moto G5?

Comment: Yes @Nimesh Neema, the SIM card currently being used in the Nokia 130 Classic is the same that I used to validate WhatsApp in Moto G5 months ago.

Comment: @biotech Okay. You cannot use the "same" WhatsApp account on two phones simultaneously. Once you activate WhatsApp on your iPhone, the one in Moto G5 will stop working. You can however access the same groups on your iPhone (basically continue using the same WhatsApp account).